# Proposal for a new Help Center section: Notation

Tags: discussion, status-completed, help-center

With the new Help Center (and even before, if I am not mistaken) it appears possible to insert (with community manager assistance) new sections that are site-specific (and moderator editable).  I propose that we request the addition of a "Notation" (or similarly named) section.  [Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/notation) and [chemistry.SE](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/notation) both have such sections, and while basic information about MathJax/$\LaTeX$ and pointers appear in our [on-topic](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page, in my opinion it makes more sense to have a dedicated section about this.

Below I have essentially just copied the content of the physics.SE notation page, with only minor changes. It is Community Wiki, so **please** improve it!

Answer (score 12):

**What notation and symbols are commonly used here?**

Many posts at Mathematics Stack Exchange include mathematical notation, written using $\mathrm\LaTeX$ commands surrounded by dollar signs. If you see dollar signs with what appears to be gibberish between them, it just means that [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/), the math rendering we use, isn't working properly for you. There are two basic types of formula:

- *Inline formulas* are surrounded by single dollar signs. For example, `$f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c$` renders as $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.
- *Block formulas* are surrounded by double dollar signs. For example, `$$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}$$` renders, *on a separate line*, as $$x = \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a}.$$

Greek letters are mostly written by simply spelling them after a backslash with capitalization indicated by first letter. For example, `$\alpha \beta \Gamma \Delta$` renders as $\alpha \beta \Gamma \Delta$.

For a quick tutorial and command reference, please see [this FAQ item](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/tex-latex-mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). See also [this discussion on the Meta site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto) for some additional pointers and references.

Comment: I've changed $\LaTeX$ to $\mathrm\LaTeX$, because the (La)TeX-code `\LaTeX`  renders not as $\LaTeX$.

Answer (score 5):

I've added [a page about notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) for you; it's moderator-editable, so if you want to add more information, change examples, etc. you'll be able to do that without contacting the SE team. Enjoy!